# Create folder tree from text file, folder names can contain spaces

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file and I need to create the folder tree with a **for** loop in a script.

Here's the text file I need to use.

Animals.txt

```
Animals
Animals/Cats
Animals/Cats/Bengal
Animals/Cats/Sphynx
Animals/Dogs
Animals/Dogs/Poodle
Animals/Dogs/Golden Retriever
```

Here's what I wrote in my script.

```
for i in $(cat Animals.txt)
do
mkdir "$i"
done
```

My problem is that when the loop goes into the last line, it creates two folders;
One is Animals/Dogs/Golden and the other is Retriever.
What should I write in my script to let it know "Golden Retriever " should be a single folder?

Comment: How do you know that none of the directories to be created have a newline in their name?  It seems odd to have a convention that spaces are allowed, but newlines are not.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It seems like the newline would be the separator, if that's true then it'd make sense to not allow it in fields themselves

Answer (score 2):

After browsing for a bit, I found this.
I added this to the start of my script and now the space is not considered.

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Comment: you should save and restore the IFS

Answer (score 2):

Couple small changes to OP's current code:

```
while read -r newdir            # read entire line into variable "newdir"
do
    mkdir -p "${newdir}"
done < Animals.txt
```

This generates:

```
$ find Animals -type d
Animals
Animals/Cats
Animals/Cats/Bengal
Animals/Cats/Sphynx
Animals/Dogs
Animals/Dogs/Golden Retriever
Animals/Dogs/Poodle
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do it straight simple with `xargs`:

```sh
xargs -L 50 -a Animals.txt mkdir -p
```

`xargs` would take up to 50 lines at a time and feed each line as argument to the command `mkdir -p`. That would be very efficient and straightforward.

Comment: it needs a `-d '\n'`. BTW that's for GNU xargs. +1